# jslint - validate only part of a file

Tags: javascript, jslint

I just inherited a messy messy javascript project. Like really messy.

I tried to run jslint, but of course it stopped soon after the beginning of the file.
I can't just fix everything at once, as we have bugs to fix, but I would still want to use jslint.

Is there a way I can use jslint to scan specific line ranges in the file, or otherwise scan specific parts? Or can jshint do that?

Comment: I use WebStorm to get a very clear overview of the jshint errors in fa file. In the end you will probably just want to actually fix all the errors, it's a monkey job but it should go faster then you fear if you set your mind to it.

Comment: Totally agree with you in that we should fix everything. But you know, deadlines...